# Why doesn't Conan reveal his identity at least to Ran in Detective Conan (Case Closed)?

Tags: detective-conan

Why doesn't Shinichi Kudo tell about his problem to Ran in Detective Conan, when he completely understands how much the girl loves him and suffers from pain due to him? While the truth is many times she was almost certain that Conan was Shinichi himself.

The series now has so many episodes. Come on! She needs some sympathy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Saying Conan doesn't reveal his identity is wrong, [there are 10 people who know about Conan true identity, and Conan told 2 of them. (Link contain spoiler)](http://www.detectiveconanworld.com/wiki/List_of_characters_who_know_Conan's_identity) Conan never told Ran because it's dangerous for her to know the truth. Professor Agasa warn him about it at the first time he know about Conan, [Second Chapter - The Shrunken Detective](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOecN.jpg)

Knowing her personality, Ran will risk her life to save others and most likely too help Conan to fight the Black Organization. [This chapter (chapter 434 Rotten Apple)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NBmo.jpg) is when Ran tried to save Ai from Vermouth, she risk her own life to save her

On several occasion, Shinichi wants to tell Ran the truth about his identity but chooses her safety above their happiness.

Beside, different from the others who know Conan's secret, Ran might unintentionally tell anyone about it. Closest possible, she will tell her best friend, Sonoko. For example, when Ran accidentally tell Sonoko about Oogami. (He's a wrestler who cover his real identity by wearing a mask - [Chapter 389 The Man Who Can Never Be a Wolf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjHge.jpg))

At one point Ran knew that Conan is Shinichi and actually waiting for him to tell her by himself, but as always Conan was able to trick her again.

Answer (score 3):

Remember the very first chapters which creates the setting for the story of a primary school detective. Shinichi Kudo was caught by the Black Organization when he was doing some investigation, and he was force-fed the drug, which is supposed to kill him (but he only shrink to the body of a child).

Although his small body is inconvenient in everyday life, it is the best possible condition for Shinichi to continue investigating the Black Organization, since the Black Organization doesn't know that he is still alive and in the form of a child.

If he were to reveal his identity to Ran, knowing her personality, she is likely to help him in his investigation, which would put her in danger of being eliminated to keep her mouth shut. Not to mention that it might involve not just her but many people around them.

Comment: (This is an answer cooked up from my patchy memories of the series)

Answer (score 0):

I’ll say revealing his identity to Ran is wrong because she might tell it to her best friend Sonoko, and Sonoko might tell others about it too and it's not all, the Black Organization might know and Ran could be their target and others might get involved and get killed.

Answer (score 0):

Because the writer wants to create a kind and strong maiden who is waiting for Shinichi.

After all, the reason the writer has given is baseless and fans who are supporting it are just pawns trying to prove a baseless reason right created by the writer that if he tells her his identity then she will be in danger

According to me, only foolish people will support this. It doesn't matter if Shinichi tells her or not, her life will be in danger because the organisation will kill her too upon knowing Conan's identity no matter if she is innocent.

And according to me, Rachel (Ran) would have supported him like Hattori. After all, if she had known about the organisation, she can also take necessary precautions and can cover his identity more effectively.